# C#, TreeView, adding nodes to node but count = zero

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, treeview, nodes

I have this peculiar problem, where I am adding nodes to nodes in a treeview.
It is something about making a explorer-like directory tree from my HD, and instead of loading all directories at once, I only do one 'level'. When clicked to expand, the next 'level' of that particulary folder is loaded.

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(par_path);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            tn_work = new TreeNode();
            tn_work.Text = d.Name;
            tn_work.ImageIndex = 0;
            tn_work.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
            par_treenode.Nodes.Add(tn_work);
            if (par_treenode.Text == "Visual Studio")
                in_test = par_treenode.Nodes.Count;
         }
```

I call this for each 'step' in making the tree for i.e. this path: "G:\Visual Studio\Projects\Project1\Work".
Meaning, first I call for "G:\Visual Studio", and this procedure loads up all folders in "Visual Studio" folder. Then I call for "G:\Visual Studio\Projects\" and it loads up all folders in the 'Projects'-folder, etc.

The 'par_treenode' is the treenode which is expanding as I go down the path. The nodes should look like this:

C:
--Visual Studio
----Projects
------Project1
--------Work

However, it does not! The folder 'Visual Studio' is added fine, but it has no nodes under it.

The problem is, that if I stop to debug this program at the 'if (par_treenode.Text == "Visual Studio")'-sentence, the node 'Visual Studio' says clearly it has 14 nodes under it. And the program works: Unfolds the entire path as it should.
But if I run it without stopping it, it has none. And the test-field I added to confirm this ('in_test = par_treenode.Nodes.Count;'), is zero.

Since stopping the program in debug-mode makes it work, it is obvious that something is going too fast. It has somehow not finished making the nodes before I ask for the count.

I have tried a wait-procedure, i have tried                     treeview1.EndUpdate(), treeview1.Refresh(); nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: Which event are you doing this in response to?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand...?
I have a treeview, and by the press of a button I'd like the treeview to reflect the folders on my HD. That's about it.

Comment: Now which is it: A Button click or the Node expansion? We may really need to exact situation to help!

Comment: It is not an event. The button click starts a form with a populated treeview. In the form startup, I populate the treeview by first getting all the drives. To provide the 'plusses' which indicates whether there is folders in the drives, I read all 'top folders' in every drive.
And if a path is provided, I'd like to open up the full path, by populating all the folders 'downwards' in the path. That is what my piece of code does (or should do).

Comment: Your question implies reacting to an event "When clicked to expand...". To which event do you listen for?

Comment: Oh, no, this is supposed to happen at startup of the form, when given a path. The path will be a string[] with the folders in each string: [G:], [Visual Studio], [Projects], etc.
The form is supposed to open the entire path given, by getting all the folders down the path populating this exact path in the treeview.